# Xubuntu: "desktop-file-utils" stopped being able to be installed

Tags: apt, package-management, xubuntu

After doing some package installs, the `desktop-file-utils` package is now failing to be installed via `apt` and `aptitude`. This is for `Xubuntu 20.04.2`.

When running `apt`, I now always get this error:

```
dpkg: error processing package desktop-file-utils (--configure):
 installed desktop-file-utils package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 desktop-file-utils
```

I know that I can purge this package, but then quite a few of its dependencies will also be uninstalled, and my system is likely to become unusable.

I don't understand what could have caused this problem, because I don't know what I could have done to affect this package.

Is there some way to fix this other than purging `desktop-file-utils` and making my system unusable? Also, is there some way where I can get more detailed information about exactly how the post-installation script is failing? If so, perhaps I could debug this.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Are you able to `apt install --reinstall` the package?

Comment: @matigo That will more likely fail. My answer explains this in detail.

Comment: Before doing the purge, would marking the dependencies as being manually installed prevent them from being removed with the purge?  `apt-mark manual pkg1 pkg2 etc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this has nothing to do with packages nor with the `apt` system.

I discovered that I had accidentally set `XDG_DATA_DIRS` to point to a non-existent directory.

Once I fixed this, the problem went away.

Here are more details as to why this fixed the problem ...

These are the contents of `/var/lib/dpkg/info/desktop-file-utils.postinst` ...

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

update-desktop-database -q

if [ "$1" = "triggered" ]; then
    exit 0
fi
```

I ran `update-desktop-database -q` from the command line, and it didn't give any output, but it exited with a non-zero return code.

I ran it again like this: `update-desktop-database -v`. This time, it gave an error message which stated that the `applications` subdirectory of the path that is contained in `XDG_DATA_DIRS` didn't exist. This showed me that I had set `XDG_DATA_DIRS` incorrectly.

Once I reset `XDG_DATA_DIRS` to a proper value, the `update-desktop-database` command started exiting with a zero return code, and the `desktop-file-utils` error in `apt` that I mentioned above stopped occurring.

Answer (score 3):

Let's fix this error step by step.

1. First, run force install to know the exact problem:

   ```
   sudo apt --fix-broken install
   ```
2. Identify the error:

   ```
   Errors were encountered while processing:
   desktop-file-utils
   ```
3. Mark dependencies as manually installed to prevent them from getting removed;

   ```
    sudo apt-mark manual libglib2.0-0 libc6
   ```
4. Remove the post-installation files:

   ```
   sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/desktop-file-utils* ~/
   ```
5. Purge the package:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -P --force-all desktop-file-utils
   ```
6. Re-install the package (Optional):

   ```
   sudo aptitude -f install desktop-file-utils
   ```

### Explanation

As the error message states:

```
installed desktop-file-utils package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

This usually implies that there are transient issues in the post-installation files.

- In the first step, we executed a command that attempted to correct the mistakes.
- In step three, we deleted the package's post-installation files.
- We purged the package in step four to remove any configuration files.
- In step five, we reinstalled the package to make sure it didn't break any other packages.

Comment: Thank you very much. However, as I mentioned in my original post, purging the package will also uninstall numerous dependencies, and this could render my OS unusable. I am trying to see if I can fix this without purging.

Comment: PS: Is there a different option, other than `--force-all` which will only purge the one package and not uninstall any of its dependencies?

Comment: @HippoMan You can try: `dpkg -r` without force-all

Comment: @HippoMan See the edit

Comment: Oh, so are you saying that after Step 5 and before Step 6, the only package which will be uninstalled would be `desktop-file-utils` and not any of its dependencies? If so, then I see that this would indeed be a "safe" way to deal with this problem.

Comment: Oh ... I'm sorry ... I missed step 3 in the edit. So ... I have to figure out all of the dependencies and then mark them as being manually installed; then, they won't be uninstalled during the purge. That raises the question of how to get an accurate list of dependencies, but perhaps I can figure that out.

Comment: @HippoMan I've already added all the dependencies in my answer.

Comment: In `aptitude`, a much longer list of dependencies is shown to me.

Comment: @HippoMan I believe those packages are further dependencies of the listed packages. I saw that on the Official Ubuntu package search. Thus, marking the packages as manual will mark all packages as manual.

Comment: Thank you, but in the recent past with a different package, I did a purge like this, and not only did the `official` Ubuntu dependencies get wiped out after the purge, but also, there were other dependencies that came from packages that I added from from other repos, and they got wiped out, also. I know for a fact that there are other such packages that I have added from other repos which are dependencies of `desktop-file-utils` directly. I will carefully find all of those and mark them as `manual` before I go forward with this. Thank you for all your help!